# Specman macros: How to use optional tags?

Tags: macros, specman, e

I have a macro for defining ports:

```
-- Create simple port
define <p_def'struct_member> "p_def <name'name> <type'type>" as {
    <name'name> : inout simple_port of <type'type> is instance;
    keep bind(<name'name>,empty);
};
```

I would like to extend the macro to support a list of ports. I would like to use for it an optional tag `[<len'name>]` that defines the list size, something like this:

```
-- Create simple port OR list of simple ports
define <p_def'struct_member> "p_def <name'name> [\[<len'name>\] ] <type'type>" as {

   if len does not exist { // How to implement it?
        <name'name> : inout simple_port of <type'type> is instance;
        keep bind(<name'name>,empty);

   } else { // len exists

        <name'name>[<len'name>] : list of inout simple_port of <type'type> is instance;
        keep for each in <name'name> {
            bind(it,empty);
        };
   };
};
```

** For example, defining a list of ports of size 10 will look this way:

```
p_def my_list_of_ports[10] bit;
```

I cannot find in Specman e Language Reference how can I know if the `optional tag` (`[<len'name>]`) is defined or not.. Do you know how to implement the "if len does not exist" statement in macro?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone is interested what is the answer:

```
define <p_def'struct_member> "p_def <name'name>[\[<len'name>\]] <type'type>" as computed {
   if <len'name> == NULL {
      result = appendf("%s : inout simple_port of %s is instance; \n keep bind(%s,empty);", <name'name>, <type'type>, <name'name>);
   } else { // list
      result = appendf("%s[%s] : list of inout simple_port of %s is instance; keep for each in %s { bind(it,empty); };", <name'name>, <len'name>, <type'type>, <name'name>);
   };
};
```

Comment: By the way, the correct name for the optional argument would be `<len'exp>` or `<len'num>` instead of `<len'name>`, because it is supposed to be a numeric expression and not a name.

Comment: And yes, using a `define as computed` macro (instead of `define as`) is exactly the way to create different alternatives depending on the input/arguments.